# Arduino with ESP8266 and c++ code

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I have the next doubt: I have Arduino UNO, or Arduino Mega, and ESP8266 wifi module. Now I want to communicate a program in C/C++ under ubuntu with Arduino by wifi to control a servo motor.

What should I do? I want indications but codes are welcome too.

Thanks.

Comment: And what is the problem you are having? If you are not sure of where to start, then your best option is to load up some examples.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how comunicate my program in c++ with ESP8266, But thanks I will see more examples.

Comment: Google could've saved you a lot of time. You can communicate directly sending AT commands from Arduino to your ESP through UART. A bench of these articles exist on instructables.com (ex: http://www.instructables.com/id/noobs-guide-to-ESP8266-with-Arduino-Mega-2560-or-U/)

Comment: But I want to comunicate c++ code[IN PC with ubuntu] to send and obtain data from arduino but using ESP8266 because I can't connect for several reasons Arduino to my pc by serial port and the aim is to control from c/c++ code arduino like a device. But thanks I will see AT too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be really simple, but here are a few ways:

1. Use both Arduino and ESP8266 (AT commands), which I do NOT recommend.
2. Use only the ESP8266, because it is much more powerful than an ATMEGA328(the Arduino processor), plus you can use it with the same interface (and pretty much the same code), see [this](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino).

Now a bit more info for the second option (I personally recommend the latter):

- You can connect both your pc and the esp8266 to the same wifi and use either TCP or UDP for communications (it will be a little work to find the server's ip though - btw, either device can be the server, so the other is the client)
- You can also use the esp8266 on the AP mode (it creates a wifi network) and set the server on it with a fixed ip and port, then you connect to this network on your pc and use a socket (either UDP or TCP, again) to exchange messages. BTW: your pc will not have internet access while connected to the esp8266

Ok, one more option (much more complicated, I think): you can create a webserver (or use an existing one, like many MQTT server avaliable for free tests) and connect both your c++ application and esp8266 to it, and then communicate using the server services (publish and subscribe for example, for MQTT).

If you want some code the link in this answer has a lot of examples and also a great community.